# display html code inside a javascript on a html page

Tags: jquery

I will try my best to explain what I wish to do and do correct me or question me if I did not get my question across correctly.

I have a jquery function as follows:

```
function processResult(xData, status) {
    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {
        var liHtml = "<a href=" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "><img src=" + $(this).attr("ows_snapshot_file_location") + " width=120 height=90><strong>" + $(this).attr("ows_video_description") + "</strong><br /><br />" + $(this).attr("ows_video_description") + "<em>" + $(this).attr("ows_video_length") + "</em></a><br />";
        $("#videoplaylist").append(liHtml);
    });
}
```

I have a HTML code as follows:

```
<div id="playlist">

/*** Something to be derive from #videoplaylist ***/

</div>
```

Actually, I can just call the jquery function as follows:

```
<div id="videoplaylist"> </div>
```

inside the

```
/*** Something to be derive from #videoplaylist ***/
```

but what I actually want was that the code to reflect all the `"lihtml"` variable.

If the `"lihtml"` variable contain

```
 <em>Hello World</em>
```

it will display `"Hello World"` in the `"/*** Something to be derive from #videoplaylist ***/"` and not

```
 <em>Hello World</em>
```

Appreciate any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to interpret this as best I can.

#### My interpretation:

You have the following in your code

```
<div id="videoplaylist">/* Something to be derive from #videoplaylist */</div>
```

and then you have a block of html (`<b>Something</b>`) that you would like to insert there like this

```
<div id="videoplaylist"><b>Something</b></div>
```

but you are getting

```
<div id="videoplaylist">/* Something to be derive from #videoplaylist */<b>Something</b></div>
```

#### Is that correct?

If so simply replace

```
$("#videoplaylist").append(liHtml);
```

with

```
$("#videoplaylist").html(liHtml);
```

The **append** command will only add the html to the end of the inside content. The **html** command will replace the complete content.

HTH
Alex

Comment: Sorry, your interpretation is not the same as what I am trying to say. The append is needed because there is a loop to gathers information and throw into the lihtml variable. the information contain html codes. I wish to have the html codes to display on the internet browser. suppose the html codes is `code`<em>Hello</em>`code`, it will display Hello in the internet browser.

Comment: Ah ok, in that case have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716944/javascript-to-add-cdata-section-on-the-fly

Or use the text function as described in the other answer (but again that will replace but not append the blob).

Comment: Hi, actually my "lihtml" just contain html codes but the link you provided mention is about xml. Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the .text function in jQuery?

$("#videoplaylist").text(liHtml);

That should output the HTML string in its CDATA form.

Comment: The text have 2 problems - one is that it will display the html codes on the internet browser (I only want to display the html codes at the source code of the page and not display on the web page itself). Also, the append is there because it is looping some rows to gather data.

Comment: I'm confused. You don't the code to display on the web page itself, but you do want "html codes to display on the internet browser" (see comment on other answer).

I'm sorry but I can't tell what you are trying to achieve. Please rephrase question or supply more details (e.g. more code if possible).

Comment: I'm sorry, likewise, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.  It now sounds like you want the html string to appear in comments (i.e. so it won't be rendered on the web page), which is sounding rather server side to me.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but that html string you are generating may not be well formed

```
var liHtml = "<a href=" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "><img src=" + $(this).attr("ows_snapshot_file_location") + " width=120 height=90><strong>" + $(this).attr("ows_video_description") + "</strong><br /><br />" + $(this).attr("ows_video_description") + "<em>" + $(this).attr("ows_video_length") + "</em></a><br />";
```

It generates an HTML string, but none of the attributes within those elements are quoted.  For example, the following string could be generating

```
<a href=title.htm><img src=image.jpg width=120 height=90>....
```

When you probably want it looking more like this to be properly parsed:

```
<a href='title.htm'><img src='image.jpg' width='120' height='90'>....
```

So hence, your auto generated html string should generate quotes around the attributes:

```
var liHtml = "<a href='" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "'><img src='" + $(this).attr("ows_snapshot_file_location") + "' width='120' height='90'>....
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction but I was wondering if it will helps to tackle my problem. Please advise.

Comment: Nope, it not working. By the way, is it possible to zip the source code and put in here?

Comment: Most people post their code to jsfiddle.net and share the link.

Comment: Actually, I am using that code for my Flow Player. Although it seems that the coding did appear as what I wish for but when clicked, it did not really activate the flow player as the flow player only accept HTML codes instead of DIV code. There is why I was thinking if the <DIV> code can "transform" itself to HTML code.