# javascript xml child node

Tags: javascript, xml

How is this done?

i read about it here: [CDATA](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Document/createCDATASection)
I've tried:

```
    var XML = document.createElement("testing");
    var NodeSystemOut = document.createElement("system-out");
    var cdata = document.createCDATASection
    ('<p>Good relations have I with the Wookies</p>');
    NodeSystem.appendChild(cdata);
    XML.appendChild(NodeSystem);
```

but this does not work.

any ideas? javascript noob

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to add cdata section on the fly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716944/javascript-to-add-cdata-section-on-the-fly)

Comment: i can't get that example to work... in the link you posted..

Comment: `doc.createCDATASection` is working for me from that example (where `doc` is a valid XML document instance)

Comment: @tkone i'm generating an xml document in a string, so this does not work for me.... if you had a look at the code above you'd realize that it will through an exception since i'm not loading in an xml file or document...

Comment: You shouldn't be using the `document.createElement` API to create XML unless `document` is an XML document. Which unless you've gone through specific lengths to do so will NOT let you use `createCDATASection`. Look through the answer linked for a better example of how to do what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a newline in your runtime code?

```
var cdata = document.createCDATASection
('<p>Good relations have I with the Wookies</p>');
```

Check that your JavaScript engine doesn't interpret these as two separate expressions. This is a perfectly legal line of JavaScript:

```
("");
```

Confusingly, JavaScript supports [implicit semicolon expression delimiters](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Semicolons#Semicolons).

So, the engine might be assigning `cdata` to a function reference:

```
var cdata = document.createCDATASection;
```